# iCheck library inputs size

Tags: css, input, size, icheck

Probably this question was asked here before as well. Unfortunately, I did not find the best answer. What would the way to change the size on inputs on this iCheck library because it is too big for my web-site.

**Css:**

```
.icheckbox_flat-blue,
.iradio_flat-blue {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(blue.png) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sep_checkbox sep_primary">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="">Google hybrid</label>
</div>
<div class="sep_checkbox sep_primary">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="">Google terrain</label>
</div>
```

If I change width or height it does not show the background properly. Show only the part of it. Any suggestions? Thank you for help.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/qhw3s7zz/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What more you need? It's enough :D.

Comment: Really? Could I demo the issue with **just that** CSS? If not...then it's not enough.

Comment: Everything else is js library.

Comment: Then that's what you need to demo. Where is the HTML etc. What image are you using? Can you link that. See the issue?

Comment: JSFIDDLE does not show the real situation but the main thing is  that I want to resize my inputs to smaller ones.

Comment: change label and input to whatever size you wish -- https://jsfiddle.net/6q8ag4mw/

Answer (score 2):

In icheck directory there is a skin folder which contains sprites of checkbox with the name (green.png, red.png) color that is you are using. simply open it in photoshop and resize it there.

if you resize it using code of above class it will effect when you hover and will change the position of check when you select it.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805394/how-to-change-size-of-icheck-checkbox-and-add-border-radius